# Android vs. WindowsMobile consuming WebService

Tags: android, web-services, windows-mobile

Scenario:

- I am developing an app for `Windows Mobile`, with `Vb.net` 2005.
- I am developing an app for `Android` with `Eclipse`.

Both apps have the same logic. Both apps consume the same web services.

The server is running in `Windows Server 2003`, and the service app was deploy using `VB.net 2005`.

The test:

- Samsung Galaxy S2 with `Android`.
- Someone Chine device with `Windows Mobile`.

The same webservice call takes:

- `Android` time : 3 min 44 seconds.
- `Windows Mobile` time: 0 min 54 seconds.

Time was calculated using a clock, and represent the time user.

Differences:

- `Windows Mobile` sends and receives datatables.
- `Windows Mobile` sends photos by Base64 serialization (5 photos 30kb each)
- `Android` sends and receives `JSON` (datatable are converted to `JSON`)
- `Android` sends photos by Base64 serialization (5 photos 30kb each)

Why time are so different?

In `Android` I consume the webservice using the following code:

public class Func_WebService {

```
private static int Ksoap_timeout = 40000; 
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String URL="http://XXX.137.xxx.79/Sincro_test_android/Service1.asmx";

private static  SoapObject request=null;
private static  SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=null;
private static  SoapPrimitive  resultsRequestSOAP=null;

public static String PRIMERLOGGIN(String Usuario,String Contrasena,String Emei){

    final String METHOD_NAME = "PRIMERLOGGIN";
    final String SOAP_ACTION ="http://tempuri.org/PRIMERLOGGIN";

    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("user", Variables.Usuario); 
    request.addProperty("pass", Variables.Contrasena); 
    request.addProperty("X", Variables.Emei); 

    envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; //se asigna true para el caso de que el WS sea de dotNet
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {       
        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        return resultsRequestSOAP.toString() ;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        return Estados_Sincro.Error_coneccion;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the code snippet you are using ksoap2-android. This library is for SOAP webservices. However you are talking about Android using JSON.. as such that won't work. You have to either change the server to use SOAP and keep using ksoap2-android or you change to the android app to parse JSON with some other library..

Comment: It works. I adapted the web service methods for json, obviously. But, the service methods has the same logical.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use datatables? I'm assuming your are serializing with Json the datable?
So you are getting a lot of extra data. The deserialization is a time consuming process.

I see you are using a login method. I have implemented some login options for j2me and windows mobile. But I always prefer custom objects and the response time it's the same.

Comment: @R Quijano The code snippet was only an example. The json datatable is this for example : [{"ID_INSPEC":255843,"MARCA":"CHEVROLET","MODELO":"CORSA GL 1.6 3 P","ANIO":1234,"CHASIS":"M","MOTOR":"M","COLOR":2,"KILOMETROS":"1111","VERIFICO":"N","ASIENTOS":"5","VTV_NUM":"11111111","VTV_VTO":"05/2009","Odom_5":"N","TIPOVEHICULO":16,"PATENTE":"EOS180","COMBUSTIBLE":1}] That´s all. I have 5 methods like this.